# Can't create an object of SolidWorks (new SldWorks()) using C# in VisualStudio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, solidworks

When I try to

```
SldWorks SwApp = new SldWorks();
```

or

```
SldWorks SwApp = null;
object processSW = Marshal.GetActiveObject("SldWorks.Application");
SwApp = (SldWorks)processSW;
```

and then try to debug - visual studio show me the error "library not registered".

When I try to register SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll library by regsvr32 I recive message "entry point DllRegisterServer not found".

I have this dll in references, but nothing work. Help me please.

Windows 10 64bit
SOlidWorks 2014 64bit
VisualStudio 2015 RC

Comment: Are you targeting your app "x64" or "AnyCPU" platform (if SolidWorks on your computer is 64bit, then you probably should)?

Answer (score 0):

It was trouble with Windows 10 TP. There are no way to register the reference dll correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register swpublished dll like so :

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\api\redist\SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished.dll" /codebase
```